# How to copy a string array into another string array?

Tags: arrays, string, go

I have an array of string elements, and I want to copy the values over to a new array.

How can I do that?

Comment: Assignment or [`copy`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy).

Comment: Technically `assign`. SEO wise people will probably find this Q&A by searching for `copy` though.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a new array of the same type and copy over the values by assigning it.

```
// Declare a string array of five elements.
var array1 [5]string

// Declare a second string array of five elements.
// Initialise the array with values.
array2 := [5]string{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}

// Copy the values from array2 into array1.
array1 = array2
```

---

Keep in mind that you **cannot** assign over an array of different size:

```
// Declare a string array of four elements.
var array1 [4]string

// Declare a second string array of five elements.
// Initialize the array with colors.
array2 := [5]string{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}

// Copy the values from array2 into array1.
array1 = array2

Compiler Error:
cannot use array2 (type [5]string) as type [4]string in assignment
```

Comment: Right you can copy but not assign.